# How to find another process that's using same file I'm trying to process?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, network-shares, process

I have a program that

1. copies a ZIP file from a network path A to network path B
2. and then unzips a file in same location (network path B)

and then I got the following error popping up.

How can I locate which process is that ***another process*** in the screenshot?

The message below showing up on the step 2.
I confirmed it copies ZIP file successfully. The error belongs to when it's trying to unzip a file.

[image]

Comment: Type `openfiles /?`. NB You need to turn on tracking for local files using `openfiles` then reboot before it will track local open files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a program like *Nirsoft*'s **Open Files Viewer** 

[OpenedFilesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) - "View opened/locked files in your system". 

It is a small Free Windows system program.